# Deciding if a ball is inside a goal via Image Processing

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I have an app which can track the ball perfectly at all time

I want to know if a ball is inside a goal , The problem I am facing is how to decide it when you have only a 2d vision of the goal and there is a situation like this
[image]

Even as a human its difficult for me to decide whether this ball is inside a goal or not, are there any algorithms or Image processing tricks that might help?

Comment: Given the camera angle, it won't be as simple as checking whether the ball contour is in a particular ROI. You can track the radius of the ball as well...the closer the ball is to the goal, the smaller its radius

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar problem - we tried to detect if the tennis ball strikes ground inside the court or outside.
The algorithm was as follow:
We used 2 (or more) cameras for detection.

1. First cameras were calibrated automatically, Court was found using Hough-Line Detector and then cameras were calibrated using Tsai Camera Calibration method. Here we used known size of the court.
2. Then the moving ball was detected. We split the trajectory of a ball into parts before and after striking ground.
3. Using the position of a camera we constructed the camera-emissive 3d surface of the ball's moovemet, and having 2 such surfaces from 2 cameras we found 3d trajectory of the ball.
4. When 2 trajectories (before and after strike) are found, detecting of a strike point and testing it with court boundaries is not very complex.

It took about 3 month for 3 not very experienced students in our laboratory.